# Is there a way to find out the source of copied text while copy pasting using windows clipboard?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, copy-paste

Suppose I have a textarea. User copy pastes data into it, from wherever. Is there a way to find out if she copied the text from a browser (website) or some other application (like word or notepad)? And if she copied from browser, is there a way to know the page URL she copied it from, all of this in Javascript?

Comment: That is impossible

Comment: Do you control the copy action at all?

Comment: Nope, I don't control the copy action.  I thought it is not possible, just wanted to check.